# how to animate hiding a picker view when the background is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

how can i animate hiding the picker view when the background is tapped? tried this:

```
[self.picker setHidden:YES];
```

but the picker disappears abruptly. i want it to animate downwards outside the screen. 
Note: i know how to implement the tapping background to disappear part of the post so please ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.picker.center = CGPointMake(self.picker.center.x, self.picker.center.y + self.picker.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    self.picker.hidden = YES;
}];
```

This slides the picker out to the bottom, then hides it when the animation finishes.

Comment: You can't add a CGPoint and a CGFloat.  This code won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f]; // you can set value as per you need.
    [self.picker setHidden:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
     self.picker.frame = CGRectMake(self.picker.frame.origin.x,self.picker.frame.origin.y+self.picker.frame.size.height,self.picker.frame.size.width,self.picker.frame.size.height);
}completion:^(BOOL fin) {

}];
```